# ThreadLocal<ByteArrayOutputStream> causes OutOfMemory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, thread-local

When I have my class structured like this, I end up with an OutOfMemory error.

DataHandler is called by a fixed pool of 8 threads (there is no external thread pool management. A fixed pool is created once, executed once, and if a thread dies, no new thread is created). At a time, multiple threads call DataHandler, but since byteArrayOutputStreamBuffer is threadLocal each will have its own local buffer. Each thread gets data, calls HandleData(), and once finished, repeats the loop.

The size of data passed is 2 GB. Thus, the total memory expected to be taken would be, at most, (2 GB + size of byte Array Stream) * number of threads. The maximum size of array stream should be 4 GB (double of data due to resizing in-memory). So the expected total heap would be 6*8 = 48 GB. The heap is configured to handle far far more (I have tried it upto 300 GB) and yet this issue persists.

```
public class DataHandler {
    private static ThreadLocal<ByteArrayOutputStream> byteArrayOutputStreamBuffer =
        new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    void HandleData(byte[] data) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = byteArrayOutputStreamBuffer.get();
        File tempFile = new File(getFileName());
        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(data);
            fileOutputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        } finally {
            byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the intermediate ByteArrayOutputStream then there is no OOM. I am trying to find an explanation why ByteArrayOutputStream is causing OOM.

EDIT: I see that toByteArray() would also add 2 GB more, so the total would be 64 GB.

Comment: What unholy computer do you have which has 300GB of memory for a JVM?  Might I suggest _streaming_ the data rather than storing the entire thing in a byte array?

Comment: as usual, `Threadlocal` is a code smell `99.9999999%` of the time because that percentage of the time the person does not understand what it does, how it does it and when it should or should not be used. This is not the `0.00000001%` of the time either.

Comment: From my understanding, `threadlocal` would be dangerous if thread management was opaque. Here, I am simply creating 8 threads once, and they are never re-created or replaced. I did a heapdump and I see that each of these 8 threads "owns" byteArrayOutputStreamBuffer and takes a huge amount of memory. Even if ByteArrayOutputStream is never garbage collected, I don't see how it would exceed size so much, since we reuse the same buffer.

Comment: @user2478398 some EC2 instances offer upto 500 GB memory.

Comment: What does `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();` return for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ByteArrayOutputStream` can hold at most `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8` bytes (8 bytes less than 2Gb), since it stores its data in a single `byte[]`, and array lengths are limited to that value.

If you try to put more data in, it will throw an `OutOfMemomoryError`.

Since you are putting in this much data, that's probably what happens.

You can't use `ByteArrayOutputStream` in that case.

But why do you need it? Why don't you just store the `FileOutputStream` in the ThreadLocal?